# "sparkly things" stock assets for Premiere Pro?

Tags: premiere

My wife wants a video slideshow for high school and college reunions, and the "free" (well, free with watermarks) programs have supplied assets for things like firecrackers and snow and other sparkly things; stars that spin and float around, etc.

This is an Asian thing, you might see are popular in the style.  They are usually simple line drawings, on a blank background for compositing over a main picture. The style was popular with Flash graphics back in the day, and is endemic on Chinese websites.

Where can I find these to use with Premiere Pro?

Answer (score 1):

Several years ago, Mitch Martinez created quite a stir by [releasing an enormous library of stock footage](http://mitchmartinez.com/two-years-of-stock-footage-the-story-so-far/) [shot in 4K resolution on RED cameras](http://mitchmartinez.com/gear/).  He offers a wide range of [fireworks clips](http://mitchmartinez.com/4k-fireworks-stock-footage/) that are free to download and use.  Among other things.

I have no affiliation with Mitch whatsoever.  I just know the story.